# Using Yahoo Fire Eagle on Grails / Java

Tags: java, rest, grails, oauth, geolocation

Has anyone implemented the Yahoo Fire Eagle API in a Java / Grails application? How did you do it?

I want to poll their REST web service with my Grails application. Yahoo offers some API Kits for various programming languages such as PHP, Ruby, etc. Unfortunately, there is nothing similar available for Java / Groovy (there is a Java library but it is for Android applications and mine is a pure web-app)

They use OAUTH; therefore, I installed the OAuth Plugin in my Grails application and configured it accordingly but now I am not sure how I should implement everything else. Has anyone already done this?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Signpost](http://code.google.com/p/oauth-signpost/) and the Fire Eagle discussions in the Google group. That should get you started.